# Android charting using William Chart

Tags: android, android-fragments, charts

I'm developing an android application lately, and i need to display some stats using charts. I search android-arsenal.com and i found a bunch of charting libraries,including  William chart that i chose because it seemed to be well built.

The problem is that i'm using a view pager, so the charts must be in fragments, but it seems that i can't `inflate` the fragment with the `LineChartView`

Here's some of the log:

```
04-17 02:04:10.271  32447-32447/com.aissabenz.irrigationadvisor E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.db.chart.view.LineChartView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at com.aissabenz.irrigationadvisor.ContentFragment.onCreateView(ContentFragment.java:70) ....
```

So i wonder if there's a solution to make the chart work on my fragment? and if not, which charting library should i switch, knowing that it must allow me to use it on fragments ?

**EDIT1:**
here my fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.aissabenz.irrigationadvisor.ContentFragment">

<com.db.chart.view.LineChartView
    xmlns:chart="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linechart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#00BBA7"
    chart:chart_axisColor="@android:color/white"
    chart:chart_typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
    chart:chart_labelColor="@android:color/white"
    chart:chart_axisBorderSpacing="0dp">
</com.db.chart.view.LineChartView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    />
```

Comment: Can you show us the XML file the error message mentions?

Comment: Do you have `Roboto-Regular.ttf` in your `assets` folder? And I would also test it with some explicit height set, just in case.

Comment: ah that's the problem, thank you :) put it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `Roboto-Regular.ttf` to your assets folder, else remove the `chart:chart_typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"` line if you don't care about using such custom font.